# Key Distribution Center Key Protocol Analysis

Tags: public-key, protocol-design, authentication, key-exchange, protocol-analysis

[image]

As shown in the image, why is Circle 1 to be B and Circle 2 to be A?

Why is not the opposite, that is, Circle 1 to be A and Circle 2 to be B? like this picture [image]

From my understanding, Notation B in 2nd picture is used to prevent from reflection attack. So in the 1sst picture, isn't that arrangement cannot prevent from reflection attack?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry about the missing pictures. i have changed it

Comment: OK, removed my remark and downvote as promised. If you have a source for the pictures (I presume a specific protocol) then please include it as well.

Comment: ... Could you please be so nice to host those images on a provider that supports SSL so people using it won't get mixed content warnings when browsing this site? (If you don't know any, use SE's built-in "add picture" function)

Comment: My spontaneous guess: You put the name of your communication partner into the key ticket to ensure they know for which communication session they are (this may be helpful especially if things scale). Additionally it may protect from some (advanced?) impersonating attacks.

Comment: on a more basic level : ​ Parties (A and B) are assumed to already know _their own_ identity. ​ ​ ​ ​